# Entity Framework Core: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to update my database and I'm getting the follwowing error:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_StudentAnnouncements_Students_StudentId' on table 'StudentAnnouncements' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I get this error when I try to update my database using
dotnet ef database update

I have a one to many relationship between student and StudentAnnouncement.
Part of the Student Entity is as below:

```
public class Student
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<StudentAnnouncement> StudentAnnouncements { get; set; }
    }
```

Part of my StudentAnnouncement Entity is as below:

```
public class StudentAnnouncement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }
```

In my database context class I have the following code:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAnnouncement>()
                     .HasOne(x => x.Student)
                     .WithMany(y => y.StudentAnnouncements)
                     .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
         
      }
```

I have tried using IsRequired instead of OnDelete Cascade as below and I get the same error

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentAnnouncement>()
             .HasOne(x => x.Class)
             .WithMany(y => y.StudentAnnouncements)
             .IsRequired();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the classes. And if you use net5 you don' t need any Fluent API

```
public class Student
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }

       public virtual ICollection<StudentAnnouncement> StudentAnnouncements { get; set; }
    }


public class StudentAnnouncement
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

          public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Just tried it, but its not working. Also, I'm using a shadow foreign key property

Comment: This is why you have the problems. You have to migrate this model to the new DB.

Comment: I have created a migration using [dotnet ef migrate] and then I did [dotnet ef database update] and thats when I'm getting the error

Comment: What are you trying to update. How it was before?

Comment: I had  added the StudentId foreign key property to StudentAnnouncements entity like you suggested and so I created a migration afterwards and then I ran dotnet ef database update for this migration to have effect

Comment: Have you removed all fluent Apis too?

Comment: I removed the fluent Apis and I'm still getting the same error message

Comment: How it could be  if you don't specify any OnDelete methods?

Comment: I was making a mistake its working now if I remove the fluent APIs but I get an error when I try to delete a record that has a child entity linked. So I have to use the fluent APIs to have onDelete cascade.